Identify TV show from the early 2000s about an orphan girl
It was a show about a young city girl (orphan, i think), that ends up living with distant relatives in a farm. 

Welcome, Forjz. I don't know how the teensie bit of information you provided allowed for a correct answer, but whatever works ;-) In the future, adding more detail will probably serve you better!

Just judging by that small bit of information, it sounds to me like it could be Caitlyn's Way
It is about a delinquent girl that gets sent to her mother's cousin's house in Montana on their ranch instead of going to a juvenile detention center.
It aired on Nickelodeon around 2000 and lasted until about 2002.  Caitlyn is a ward of the state due to her mother dying when she was 8 and her father nowhere to be found.

Wow; you're good. Thats exactly it! Thanks, i used to love that show when i was younger
